# Edge Detection Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to take the gradient of the image and expect that if the difference between neighbor pixel values are big. Change my pixel value. I am not trying to use any opencv functions by the way. Here is the code I am trying to work, but the result of the code stays on its initial state.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('coins.jpg',0)
rows,cols = img.shape
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if(((i+1) <= rows) and ((j+1) <= cols) and ((i-1) >= rows) and ((j-1) >= cols)):
            value = img[i,j]
            value1 = img[i+1,j]
            value2 = img[i-1,j]
            value3 = img[i,j+1]
            value4 = img[i,j-1]
            value5 = img[i+1,j+1]
            value6 = img[i+1,j-1]
            value7 = img[i-1,j-1]
            value8 = img[i-1,j+1]
            if(abs(value - value1) >= 10):
                value = 255
            if(abs(value - value2) >= 10):
                value = 255
            if(abs(value - value3) >= 10):
                value = 255
            if(abs(value - value4) >= 10):
                value = 255
            if(abs(value - value5) >= 10):
                value = 255
            if(abs(value - value6) >= 10):
                value = 255
            if(abs(value - value7) >= 10):
                value = 255
            if(abs(value - value8) >= 10):
                value = 255
cv2.imshow('Difference Im', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition:

```
if(((i+1) <= rows) and ((j+1) <= cols) and ((i-1) >= rows) and ((j-1) >= cols)):
```

Can never be true because i is between 0 and rows-1 (i.e. i-1 is never >=rows), and j is between 0 and j-1 (so j-1 is never >=cols), so the processing it controls can never happen.

Plus, the condition doesn’t make much sense - what you want is for i to be between 1 and rows-2, and j between 1 and cols-2, so the correct condition is (also removing all those c-style `()` because these are all and-ed together):

```
if i>=1 and i<=rows-2 and j>=1 and j<=cols-2:
```

This should work.

I can’t test this now but you may be able to make this even more succinct like:

```
 if 1<=i<=rows-2 and 1<=j<=cols-2:
```

Even better you could make the for statements use the range 1,rows-1 and 1,cols-1 then you don’t need the if statement at all :-)

You could diagnose this yourself simply by adding a `print` statement below the `if` statement then you would see these statements are never executed, which is why your image never changes.

Also you should make your magic number 10 a variable that you initialize once, so if you ever need to change the threshold you only need to edit that one initialization rather than 8 comparisons.

And it should be possible to make the threshold comparison a couple of nested loops so you don’t have all that repeated code.